# Unable to connect internal apps using tailscale server name with specified port

Tags: oracle, plex, tailscale

As the title suggest, I want to basically disable the public TCP port and allow plex or other apps to only connect using Tailscale.

Like, I don't want to allow `server-public-ip:32400`, but instead I wanna do `tailscale-server-name:32400`.

If I have the port opened in TCP for all sources it works, doesn't work when I remove the ingress rule.

[image: oracle-vcn]

The server pings fine (MagicDNS enabled)

```
Pinging oracle.hidden-name.ts.net [tailscale-ip] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from tailscale-ip: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=64
Reply from tailscale-ip: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=64
Reply from tailscale-ip: bytes=32 time=38ms TTL=64
Reply from tailscale-ip: bytes=32 time=37ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for tailscale-ip:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 36ms, Maximum = 38ms, Average = 36ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. It won't work with only machine name as it won't resolve HTTP/S, will work with Tailscale IP or the `ts.net` domain.

Answer (score 0):

> If I have the port opened in TCP for all sources it works, doesn't work when I remove the ingress rule.

That likely means the apps connecting to plex are still using the LAN IP address, not the Tailscale IP address. Using [MagicDNS](https://tailscale.com/kb/1081/magicdns/) might help, the Plex app can be told to go to plex.example.com.beta.tailscale.net.

Comment: I have MagicDNS already turned on, and the server also pings fine using the server name.

Updated the post with more details.

Comment: Okay it works on http://oracle.hidden-name.ts.net:32400, I was trying to do oracle:32400.